# code works in code pen but not in vs code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I have a next button that's supposed to go to the next fieldset in a form. It works in the code-pen(https://codepen.io/atakan/pen/nPOZZR) in which I found it the. There were people asking about this same problem but the solution is supposed to be just adding the jquery cdn call but that did not work. anyone know whats up with this? (there is no error messages and I'm using Django version 4.2.3)   this html:

```
<!-- multistep form -->
{%load static%}


<head>
  <!-- ... your other links and scripts ... -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/profile_completion.js' %}"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/profile_completion.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
      <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
      <li>Social Profiles</li>
      <li>Personal Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
      <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
      <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
      <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
      <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
      <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
      <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
      <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <a href="https://twitter.com/GoktepeAtakan" class="submit action-button" target="_top">Submit</a>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
```

and this javascript:

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
    
    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
    
    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    
    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
    
    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
```

I've tried adding different versions of jQuery.

Comment: Learn to debug - open the developer console in your browser and check to see what the error is. Also, I'm assuming from the context that you're running this code *within* VSCode somehow. I would strongly suggest you never do that. Always run in an actual browser.

Comment: The CodePen also includes the following CDN, *cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js*

Comment: yeah I've done all that like I said there is no error and I'm running it within chrome to test it out

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The script was running before the DOM was ready, so I just added:

```js
$(document).ready(function(...))
```